# C ptrace breakpoints

Tags: c, debugging, ptrace

I have been using [this](http://www.alexonlinux.com/how-debugger-works) tutorial to try to set up a debugger in C. I have set up a test program, which looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("BEFORE");

    printf("AFTER"); 
}
```

and the dissasembly for the main function looks like this: 
[image]

but if i try to use the code below to print data at 0x64a, i get the output `ffffffffffffffff`

```
long address = 0x64a;
long data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, status, (void *) address, NULL);
printf("%lx", data);
```

Also, this is the code where i attach the test program:

```
char* args[] = {"test", NULL};
if(pid == 0)
{
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
    execve("./test", args, NULL);
    //execl("./test", "test", NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a position-independent executable. As such, ASLR makes it start at a random address in memory. Check the `rip` register during `ptrace` and dump the code from there, instead of from the address in your executable.

Comment: if i understand correctly, i've done something similar and it has similar results. Asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531930/ptrace-doesnt-show-the-same-as-objdump